# Forward-Backward Algorithm explanations

Tags: hidden-markov-model, forward-backward

I am studying the Forward-Backward Algorithm from [HMMs and the forward-backward algorithm by Ramesh Sridharan](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rameshvs/content/hmms.pdf)

I don't understand how to get $(1,3,4)^{T}$ in the example below. Could someone help to explain the steps? Thanks  [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do the multiplication and addition you get (0.25, 0.75, 1), try multiplying this vector by 4, you get (1,3,4) and hence you have the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why multiply the vector by 4 ? There're only three state variables and two possible observations, hot and cold.

Comment: The next line in that reference states: "Since our probabilities are eventually computed by multiplying messages and normalizing,
we can arbitrary renormalize at any step to make the computation easier."